# Tikz automata: Make labels more visible (not overlap)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following code:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture} [shorten >=1pt, node distance=4cm, auto]
    \node [state, initial]   (00)                 {$(0, 0)$};
    \node [state]            (10) [right = of 00] {$(1, 0)$};
    \node [state]            (20) [right = of 10] {$(2, 0)$};
    \node [state]            (01) [above = of 00] {$(0, 1)$};
    \node [state]            (11) [right = of 01] {$(1, 1)$};
    \node [state, accepting] (21) [right = of 11] {$(2, 1)$};

    \path [->]
        (00) edge              node {a, b} (21)
        (10) edge              node {a}    (01)
        (11) edge [bend right] node {b}    (10)
        (10) edge [bend right] node {b}    (11)
        (20) edge              node {a}    (11)
        (20) edge [bend right] node {b}    (21)
        (01) edge              node {a, b} (20)
        (11) edge              node {a}    (00)
        (21) edge              node {a}    (10)
        (21) edge [bend right] node {b}    (20);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which results in this drawing:
[image: automata]

Now how do I ensure that the labels are clearly readable without changing the position of the nodes?

Comment: You should play with `xshift` and/or `yshift`.

Comment: @projetmbc Where would I place these attributes?

Comment: For example, you can try `(00) edge node[yshift=-22pt] {a, b} (21)` .

Comment: Well, where do you want to have the labels? You can use the [`pos` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/pos) or the predefined `near start` (`pos = .25`) and `near end` (`pos = .75`)  keys to change the position along the arrow. You can `swap` the position of the label to the other side. And lastly, yes, you can shift the position of the label directly. You can also use `sloped` which rotates the label such that it follows the direction of the arrow.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That was helpful, thanks!

Comment: Welcome @mtxcactus. // Sounds like you now could solve your problem. If so, feel free to post an answer too, showing your approach using shift or pos. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `pos` and `sloped` I was now able to get it to look more appealing. But I'm sure you could make it look even more visually pleasing.

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture} [shorten >=1pt, node distance=4cm, auto]
    \node [state, initial]   (00)                 {$(0, 0)$};
    \node [state]            (10) [right = of 00] {$(1, 0)$};
    \node [state]            (20) [right = of 10] {$(2, 0)$};
    \node [state]            (01) [above = of 00] {$(0, 1)$};
    \node [state]            (11) [right = of 01] {$(1, 1)$};
    \node [state, accepting] (21) [right = of 11] {$(2, 1)$};

    \path [->]
        (00) edge [pos=.15, sloped]    node {a, b} (21)
        (10) edge [pos=.15, sloped]    node {a}    (01)
        (11) edge [bend right]         node {b}    (10)
        (10) edge [bend right]         node {b}    (11)
        (20) edge [near start, sloped] node {a}    (11)
        (20) edge [bend right]         node {b}    (21)
        (01) edge [pos=.15, sloped]    node {a, b} (20)
        (11) edge [pos=.15, sloped]    node {a}    (00)
        (21) edge [near start, sloped] node {a}    (10)
        (21) edge [bend right]         node {b}    (20);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: An even better looking automata]